# Error 403 when trying to access localhost

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu, localhost, http-status-code-403

Good morning all.

I run a small in office dev (xampp) server for the build of static and WordPress websites on my Ubuntu machine.

I use vhosts for which two are workingabsolutly fine. However, I have another which for some reason keeps failing when I try to load the site.

My Xampp install is a typical /opt/lampp install, nothing unique or special.

My vhosts File

```
##Summerschool Development Version (which works fine)
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs/summerschooldev"
    ServerName summerschoolforteensuk.com
    <Directory "/opt/lampp/htdocs/summerschooldev/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

##Summerschool old website (which works fine)
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs/summerschool"
    ServerName summerschoolold.com
    <Directory "/opt/lampp/htdocs/summerschool/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

##scp old website throws error 403 You don't have permission to access / on this server..
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs/scp"
    ServerName scpold.com
    <Directory "/opt/lampp/htdocs/scp/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Now my hosts file

```
127.0.0.1   summerschoolforteensuk.com
127.0.0.1   summerschoolold.com
127.0.0.1   scpold.com
```

From what I can see, everything seems to be working fine. Im relativly new to working like this but poor internet speed at my office means I have to. Im guessing that there is not error here as the other two sites work fine.

Is there something Im missing if not where would I look next.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried by updating your database accordingly?

Comment: @ShravanShrama I had actually made some changes to the DB by removing some what i thought to be wasted tables that I didn’t need. Im importing the original and see what happens.

Comment: I think you didn't update your `home_url` and `site_url` key in `options` table.

Comment: No they are fine, besides 403 is a server error not a problem with wp.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have solved this by installing wordpress locally and importing my database and wp-content folder into the install and using the full domain for the server name and host.

Dont think this has solved my issue but its working now.